# mySQL - Show data per year based on user selection

Tags: mysql

I currently having a dilemma how to do these with my current project.

I have this table in database:

[image: Showing data for amount and the date it was entered.]

Now I''m trying to figure out how to do this in mysql.

- The user will select year from a drop down or combo box
- Upon choosing a year, a table will display all the months as a column with the corresponding amount per month

Sample output if 2016 is the selected year.

[image]

Appreciate your help and expertise. I'm just a newbie guy in mySQL only less than a year of experience with it.

Maybe you can give me some tricks and ways how to do this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What did you tried and what was the result?

Comment: I do have, and I forgot to include that, I made a stored procedure like these:

Comment: CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `financial_forecast`()
BEGIN
SET group_concat_max_len=2048;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(
DISTINCT CONCAT(
'MAX(IF(savings_date = ''',
DATE_FORMAT(savings_date,'%Y'),
''', amount, 0)) AS ',
CONCAT("'",DATE_FORMAT(savings_date,'%Y'),"'")
)
) INTO @sql
FROM
net_savings;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple sketch for you would be to use case statements in aggregation.
There is a space for performance improvements in calculating first and last day of month + the where clause but this should get you started:

```
select
  sum(case when savings_date between date_format(savings_date, '%Y-01-01') and last_day(date_format(savings_date, '%Y-01-01')) then amount end) as `jan`,
  . . .
  sum(case when savings_date between date_format(savings_date, '%Y-12-01') and last_day(date_format(savings_date, '%Y-12-01')) then amount end) as `dec`
from 
  yourtable
where year(savings_date) = '2016'
```

I'm leaving calculating `total` amount for the reader as an exercise.

SQL Fiddle with sample: [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/905cea/3)

Comment: Will result in a **#1064 SQL syntax error** *(Reserved word)*.

Comment: @nyedidikeke Thans for your input. This has now been resolved by adding backticks around assigned column names and was caused by `dec` being a reserved word.

Comment: Another question, what if I want it instead per fiscal year? My fiscal year starts at Novermber and ends in october.

Comment: Then you need more sophisticated logic with year and month extraction in your where clause, or just calculate and store the fiscal year in your data while inserting